# Error in Parsing JSON android

Tags: java, android, json

I have been on an app to fetch books from API(CURRENTLY HARDCODED)

here is my java code :

```
package com.example.vidit.books;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Request extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = Request.class.getSimpleName();

    String response = "{\n"
            + "kind: \"books#volumes\",\n"
            + "totalItems: 1097,\n"
            + "items: [\n"
            + "{\n"
            + "kind: \"books#volume\",\n"
            + "id: \"MoXpe6H2B5gC\",\n"
            + "etag: \"9f/Qo6rf8Fs\",\n"
            + "selfLink: \"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/MoXpe6H2B5gC\",\n"
            + "volumeInfo: {\n"
            + "title: \"Android in The Attic\",\n"
            + "authors: [\n"
            + "\"Nicholas Allan\"\n"
            + "],\n"
            + "publisher: \"Hachette UK\",\n"
            + "publishedDate: \"2013-01-03\",\n"
            + "description: \"Aunt Edna has created a no-nonsense nanny android to make sure Billy and Alfie don't have any fun. But then Alfie discovers how to override Auntie Anne-Droid's programming and nothing can stop them eating all the Cheeki Choko Cherry Cakes they like ... until the real aunt Edna is kidnapped!\",\n"
            + "industryIdentifiers: [\n"
            + "{\n"
            + "type: \"ISBN_13\",\n"
            + "identifier: \"9781444905465\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "{\n"
            + "type: \"ISBN_10\",\n"
            + "identifier: \"1444905465\"\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "],\n"
            + "readingModes: {\n"
            + "text: true,\n"
            + "image: false\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "pageCount: 192,\n"
            + "printType: \"BOOK\",\n"
            + "categories: [\n"
            + "\"Juvenile Fiction\"\n"
            + "],\n"
            + "maturityRating: \"NOT_MATURE\",\n"
            + "allowAnonLogging: false,\n"
            + "contentVersion: \"1.2.2.0.preview.2\",\n"
            + "imageLinks: {\n"
            + "smallThumbnail: \"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=MoXpe6H2B5gC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api\",\n"
            + "thumbnail: \"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=MoXpe6H2B5gC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "language: \"en\",\n"
            + "previewLink: \"http://books.google.co.in/books?id=MoXpe6H2B5gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=android&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api\",\n"
            + "infoLink: \"http://books.google.co.in/books?id=MoXpe6H2B5gC&dq=android&hl=&source=gbs_api\",\n"
            + "canonicalVolumeLink: \"http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Android_in_The_Attic.html?hl=&id=MoXpe6H2B5gC\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "saleInfo: {\n"
            + "country: \"IN\",\n"
            + "saleability: \"FOR_SALE\",\n"
            + "isEbook: true,\n"
            + "listPrice: {\n"
            + "amount: 212,\n"
            + "currencyCode: \"INR\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "retailPrice: {\n"
            + "amount: 148.4,\n"
            + "currencyCode: \"INR\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "buyLink: \"http://books.google.co.in/books?id=MoXpe6H2B5gC&dq=android&hl=&buy=&source=gbs_api\",\n"
            + "offers: [\n"
            + "{\n"
            + "finskyOfferType: 1,\n"
            + "listPrice: {\n"
            + "amountInMicros: 212000000,\n"
            + "currencyCode: \"INR\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "retailPrice: {\n"
            + "amountInMicros: 148400000,\n"
            + "currencyCode: \"INR\"\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "]\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "accessInfo: {\n"
            + "country: \"IN\",\n"
            + "viewability: \"PARTIAL\",\n"
            + "embeddable: true,\n"
            + "publicDomain: false,\n"
            + "textToSpeechPermission: \"ALLOWED_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY\",\n"
            + "epub: {\n"
            + "isAvailable: true,\n"
            + "acsTokenLink: \"http://books.google.co.in/books/download/Android_in_The_Attic-sample-epub.acsm?id=MoXpe6H2B5gC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api\"\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "pdf: {\n"
            + "isAvailable: false\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "webReaderLink: \"http://books.google.co.in/books/reader?id=MoXpe6H2B5gC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_api\",\n"
            + "accessViewStatus: \"SAMPLE\",\n"
            + "quoteSharingAllowed: false\n"
            + "},\n"
            + "searchInfo: {\n"
            + "textSnippet: \"Aunt Edna has created a no-nonsense nanny android to make sure Billy and Alfie don&#39;t have any fun.\"\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "},"
            + "}";
    String APIURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_request);
        ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<Book>();
        try {
            book = extractJSON(response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BookAdapter bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, book);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_all);
        listView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String text = i.getStringExtra("text");
        APIURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android";

    }

    public static ArrayList<Book> extractJSON(String abc) throws JSONException {
        ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<Book>();

        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(abc);
            JSONArray item = root.getJSONArray("items");

            JSONObject name = item.getJSONObject(0);
            String title = name.getString("title");

            book.add(new Book(title, null));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
                // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }

        return book;

    }
}
```

Following are the erros which i encountered When my code ran .
The logcat shows these errors.
I cant understand where I am going wrong

[image: ERROR IN LOGCAT]

[image: CONTINUE ERROR IN LOGCAT]

Comment: Check if your JSON is validate ... use http://www.jsonlint.com

Comment: your json is error full

Comment: Try some online json formatters like : [freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html) and [Jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). use it to check for your errors.

Comment: Second to last line of the JSON has a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the square brackets`[]` pair up and the parenthesis`()` pair up as well in your Json String.

Check out the ff places where there are Json Arrays for some errors that I have noticed:

> ```
>     + "authors: [\n"
>     + ":\"Nicholas Allan\"\n"
>     + "],\n"
> ```

try with:

```
 + "authors: [\n{"
 + "\"name\":"+"\"Nicholas Allan\"}\n"
 + "],\n"
```

And

> ```
>     + "categories: [\n"
>     + "\"Juvenile Fiction\"\n"
>     + "],\n"
> ```

try with:

```
+ "categories: [\n{"
+ "\"name\""+":\"Juvenile Fiction\"}\n"
+ "],\n"
```

Finally, Try some online json formatters like : [freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html) and [Jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

Comment: `authors` and `categories` can be a list of strings. They don't need objects with just a `name` key

Comment: Ooops, thanks @ cricket_007, thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: The JSON seems to look fine other than the last line at `},}`

Comment: I noticed but forgot to mention that as well